# jquery fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

I am trying to integrate jquery full calendar plugin.. And I want to disable the past dates for selection.. So I can select only dates starting from current date. How is it possible? How can I filter the dates and specify a condition. I am new to jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        select: function(start, end, allDay) {
            var title = prompt('Event Title:');
            if (title) {
                calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                    {
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end,
                        allDay: allDay
                    },
                    true // make the event "stick"
                );
            }
            calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
        },
        editable: true,
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the select method, you are provided with the selected start and end date, and earlier in the method you got the current date in the `date` variable. So just compare them, and if it is less than `date`, handle the error.

```
select: function(start, end, allDay) {
  if(start < date)
  {
    // Do whatever you want here.
    alert('Cannot select past dates.');
    return;
  }

  var title = prompt('Event Title:');
  if (title) {
    calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
        title: title,
        start: start,
        end: end,
        allDay: allDay
      },
      true // make the event "stick"
    );
  }

  calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
},
```

Comment: How to set the month name as Shortmonth name as like JUL. Currently when I give start.getMonth() and alert  it displays the month as integet. I.e. for Jul 7. I want to display it as JUL

Comment: @user, you should ask another question since this is unrelated to what you originally asked. However, fullCalendar has a monthNamesShort array (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/text/monthNamesShort/) so just do something like `monthNamesShort[start.getMonth()]`

Comment: so in the above code if I try to alert (monthNamesShort[start.getMonth()]); then will i get the month as JUL?? I am newbie to jquery.. So its a learning stage for me:)

Comment: I need to display it after the Prompt message above. Please help

Comment: @user, you've actually already posted another question already. I would suggest moving these comments to the other question so that you get more people to see it.

Answer (score 1):

Note regarding Brandon's answer, the popup will also appear if you click on the current date. You would need to check if the user clicked on today's date also:

```
if (start < date && start.getDate() != date.getDate() ) {
    alert('Cannot select past dates.');
    return;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to remove the past dates and next month's dates from the fullcalendar.. So for the current month it should display only current dates and days..??